# Is information propagated across a medium in any other way than waves?

Tags: waves, information

Is information propagated in any other way than waves? Please distinguish "propagation across a medium" from information "storage within stable states of matter", which might difuse or interact chemically.

Information might be stored in stable configurations of matter, which might diffuse, or interact chemically (odor,DNA), but these might be orders of magnitude weaker, in range and dissipation. Is there a domain in physics comparing wave vs non-wave propagation.  The two most known are sensory: sound and electromagnetic propagation. I think gravity probes are still searching for waves in this medium.

Why does nature prefer waves for long distance calls? Perhaps because it involves a minimum dissipation of energy?

Comment: But “A pressure pulse propagating in the water or atmosphere” _is_ a wave.

Comment: Books are an example of transmitting information through non-wave propagation

Comment: good point! If there are no non-wave methods, WHY?

Comment: like! books response... but how do you read the print in the absence of (light) waves

Comment: The reading part is common to all kinds of instrumentation. The information reaches us through our senses - usually through waves. Incidentally, smelling is another example of non-wave propagation of information.

Comment: Ultimately, you always need light (without photons you wouldn't live).

Comment: I think blind people disagree with you

Comment: I think he meant that photons are the energy source for plants, and humans rely on this food chain. But this is getting off the topic. My original reason for this post was the realization that long distance communication, which does not rely on configurations of matter, alsways involves waves. Whether acoustic or electromagnetic, we need to wiggle some matter, which radiates some of the energy to the field to wiggle something else at the sensor receiver! Maybe this should be obvious, but it was a nice surprise for me. And maybe a motivator for explorers of waves.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [legrojan's comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83435/is-information-propagated-in-any-other-way-than-waves#comment173782_83435):

Smelling is a great example of information transfer that doesn't occur via a wave. "Information" comes to your sensory organ in the form of trace molecules in the atmosphere. Those molecules get to you through a diffusion process. And the [diffusion equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_equation) is different from the [wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation).

In fact, once our sensory organs are stimulated, the information propagates in our brains partially as a wave and partially diffusively. When a nerve impulse travels down an axon, it does so as a wave called the [action potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_potential). But once that wave reaches the [synapse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synapse), the information it represents has to cross to the next nerve cell by releasing neurotransmitters which diffuse across the synaptic gap.

To reiterate: information can be transferred via diffusion, which is a method of transfer other than waves.